# Devise: Allow users to register as "UsErNaMe" but login with "username"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In the same way most websites work, I was to store "UsErNaMe" in the database but let users login with "username".

This is a fairly obvious and necessary feature, and plenty of people seem to have asked it, but the solution I keep stumbling upon seems disconnected from Devise's own documentation.

For instance, consider this blog post: http://anti-pattern.com/2011/5/16/case-insensitive-keys-with-devise

> [...]you’ve probably run into the problem that some users like to type
>   certain letters in their logins (email and/or username) in uppercase,
>   but expect it to be case-insensitive when they try to sign in. A not
>   unreasonable request[...]

Cool! That's what I want.

His solution:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email, :username]
end
```

That's the solution I keep finding. But here's the documentation for that config option:

```
# Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
# These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
# to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username, :email ]
```

In particular: "These keys will be downcased upon creating/modifying a user." In other words, the username is being downcased in the database.

To verify:

```
User.create username: "UsErNaMe", password: "secret", email: "email@com.com"
#=> <User username="username"...>
```

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address): you need to overwrite devise's `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method in your model.

ActiveRecord example:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

You can remove `OR lower(email) = :value` part if you don't need auth by email too.

That way you don't need to list `username` in `case_insensitive_keys` and it wouldn't be downcased in the database.

Comment: This of course will only work if you declared a :login virtual attribute in the user model, set that as your devise  :authentication_keys => [:login] and use that attribute in your login form.

Comment: also, though you allow case-sensitive entry in the database, you wanna make sure uniqueness is case-insensitive, otherwise, you allow both 'Username' and 'username' but the find first on lower will conflfate them on retrieval. So add validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false